# Adjusting timecodes with regular expressions in Microsoft Word 2016

Tags: regex, ms-word, word-2016

I want to use regular expressions to find/replace in MS Word 2016 to correct some timecodes in a transcript. I'm working in the Find and Replace menu, with "Use wildcards" checked.

The original timecodes are in the format [##:##:##**:**##]

I want to replace them with [##:##:##.##]

So I'm looking for **:**##] and replacing with **.**##]

(I know I could do this in Python or etc., but I'd rather do it in Word 2016.)

Comment: macropod answered my question. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

Find = :([0-9]{2}\])

Replace = .\1

If you're doing this often, you might want to record a macro for it.